# How can I use Passwordless authentication via JDBC through Azure Pipelines?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, azure-active-directory, azure-pipelines, flyway

My goal is to use Service Principals for authentications instead of passwords in my Azure environment.

In my Azure Pipelines I have a database migration script that I'm struggling to get working with ActiveDirectoryIntegrated authentication via ADAL4J.

Environment:

- CI/CD: Azure Pipelines
- OS: Ubuntu (latest)
- Java: OpenJDK 11
- Database: Azure SQL
- Database Migration Tool: Flyway (v6.0.1)

My simplified script showcases what I want to achieve.

```yaml
variables:
  FLYWAY_VERSION: '6.0.1'

pool:
  vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"

  - task: AzureCLI@2
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'MyServicePrincipalSubscription'
      scriptType: 'bash'
      scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
      inlineScript: |

        # Install Flyway
        curl -L https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/flywaydb/flyway-commandline/$(FLYWAY_VERSION)/flyway-commandline-$(FLYWAY_VERSION)-linux-x64.tar.gz -o flyway.tar.gz
        tar -xzf flyway.tar.gz

        # Run migrations
        ./flyway-$(FLYWAY_VERSION)/flyway \
          -locations="filesystem:./DataChanges/test" \
          -url="jdbc:sqlserver://***;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated" \
          migrate -X
```

This results in an error loading ADAL4J, no matter what I try.

```bash
SQL State  : null
Error Code : 0
Message    : Failed to load both sqljdbc_auth.dll and ADAL4J Java library for performing ActiveDirectoryIntegrated authentication. Please install one of them to proceed.
```

I have tried the following

- Adding ADAL4J manually to JARS

```bash
curl -L https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/microsoft/azure/adal4j/1.6.6/adal4j-1.6.6.jar -o adal4j.jar

mv adal4j.jar flyway-$(FLYWAY_VERSION)/jars/

DEBUG: Adding location to classpath: /home/vsts/work/1/s/flyway-6.0.1/jars/adal4j.jar <-- Confirmation of loading.
```

- Changing to Windows VM and using Powershell

```yaml
pool:
  vmImage: "windows-latest"


  - task: AzureCLI@2
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'MyServicePrincipalSubscription'
      scriptType: 'ps'
```

Comment: There's some confusion here, in the title you want to use "Active Directory Integrated authentication", but at the beginning of the question you want to use Service Principals for authentication. ActiveDirectoryIntegrated and ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal are different authentication methods. See the detailed info from [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-using-azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: To use `authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated` authentication mode, you must federate the on-premises Active Directory Federation Services (ADFS) with Microsoft Entra ID in the cloud. Once it's set up, you can connect by either adding the native library mssql-jdbc_auth-<version>-<arch>.dll to the application class path on Windows, or by setting up a Kerberos ticket for cross-platform authentication support.

Comment: `authentication=ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal` can be used to connect to an Azure SQL/Synapse Analytics by specifying the application/client ID in the userName property and secret of a service principal identity in the password property.

Answer (score 0):

As advised by Ziyang Liu-MSFT, my approach was not correct.
What worked for me and seems to be the standard is the following.

Use `ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal` along with Client ID/Secret in the connection string.

Flyway v6 JDBC does not include support for `ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal`, therefore an upgrade is required as well.

```yaml
variables:
  FLYWAY_VERSION: '8.5.13'

pool:
  vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"

steps:
  - script: |

      # Install Flyway
      curl -L https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/flywaydb/flyway-commandline/$(FLYWAY_VERSION)/flyway-commandline-$(FLYWAY_VERSION)-linux-x64.tar.gz -o flyway.tar.gz
      tar -xzf flyway.tar.gz

      # Run migrations
      ./flyway-$(FLYWAY_VERSION)/flyway \
        -locations="filesystem:./DataChanges/test" \
        -url="jdbc:sqlserver://***;user=$(CLIENT_ID);password=$(CLIENT_SECRET);Authentication=ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal" \
        migrate -X
```